I94 Admit Until Date update
My I94 Admit Until Date update is about to expire on sep 2024. But I got my new renewd passport and h1b extention recently.
1.How can I update the admit until date in my I94?
2.When can I use new renewd passport number to check my I94 history. Right now it says no history found.

If you got an H1b petition approval along with an Extension of Stay approval, you would have received an I-797A approval notice, which will have a paper I-94 as part of the page. That is your new I-94, and supersedes any I-94s you may have received previously, including the I-94 that you received on your last entry. If you received the Extension of Stay approval after your last entry, then this new paper I-94 is your only valid I-94 at present, and should be the I-94 you present anywhere an I-94 is needed.
The CBP's I-94 website will only have I-94s that were issued at entry. The paper I-94 you just got from USCIS from your Extension of Stay approval will not show up on the CBP's I-94 website. If you received the Extension of Stay approval after your last entry, then the electronic I-94 on the the CBP's I-94 website is no longer valid and should not be used from now on, since you got a newer I-94.

Thanks for clarification.
